# Automatically creating Heroku apps via webhooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I need to programmatically spawn up Heroku apps.

For example, to start a new app I would normally run `heroku apps:create appname`, but I want to be able to use some sort of a webhook so I can automatically execute this when there's a request, instead of me doing this on my computer. Is this possible?